# Giving two different users permissions to a dir

Tags: linux

I have a script that is run sometimes via the web, sometimes via the command line. When the script is run via web, it's run via user `www-data`. When it's run via command line, it's run via user `jason`.

This script writes to a directory called `cache`.

- If I `chown -R jason cache`, I can run the script as `jason` but not `www-data`. This makes sense.
- If I `chown -R www-data cache`, I can run the script as `www-data` but not `jason`. This also makes sense.

I tried creating a group called `scripts`, adding my two users, then `chown`ing `cache` to `scripts`. I'm not really sure how to do the last part, the `chown`ing part. The Linux command docs I've found online for this are astoundingly bad.

I don't know if I explained this all that well but hopefully it's clear what I'm trying to do. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually with chown you'd do:

> chown user:group (files)

Is that not working? Can you check and make sure the files are owned by the group, and that the second group of permissions is at least r-x?

`-rwxr-xr-x  1 user group   44380 2009-02-10 13:10 junk`

Comment: `drwxrwxrwx 4 jason    scripts 4096 2010-12-21 11:20 cache`

Comment: That looks fine. It seems that the problem is this: if `jason` creates a file, then later `www-data` wants to overwrite that file, it can't do it.

Comment: @jason swett: When he's creating it, I assume he's creating it jason:jason, rather than jason:scripts

Comment: Okay, it turns out if I delete any of those files before I try to open them, they can be opened by either user.

Comment: You need to look at warner's setuid line: **chmod g+s directory** This will force the files created in the directory to inherit the directories group. That should solve the permission issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`chgrp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chgrp) or [`chown`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) when specifying `user:group` instead of just `user`.

You will likely want to specify the [SGID bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#setuid_and_setgid_on_directories), so as that the group ownership is maintained on creation.  You can do this using `chmod g+s directory`.

You will also need to insure that the write and execute bits are set for the group, which can be done with `chmod g+wx`.